# Android - Disallow Fabric beta distribution

Tags: android, code-signing, twitter-fabric, bitrise

I want to not allow the devs from my organization to deploy a beta using Fabric, but I don't see how.

The Fabric secret is committed in the repository, so if they run the gradle script:

```
assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease
```

the APK will be uploaded, as all the signature stuff is also added in the gradle config file.

The only way for deploying into Fabric we want to allow is using `Bitrise` (our ci platform).

I was thinking on removing the `fabric.properties` file (containing the Fabric Secret) from the repo, adding that secret somewhere in a Bitrise config variable but I'm not sure it'll work.

Any idea about a solution for this problem?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just remove `crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease` from the Gradle params? Re:"I was thinking on removing the fabric.properties file (containing the Fabric Secret) from the repo, adding that secret somewhere in a Bitrise" - Bitrise.io has a feature called "Generic File Storage" which was designed to store these kinds of files - http://devcenter.bitrise.io/tutorials/how-to-use-the-generic-file-storage/

Comment: I can remove it, but if a developer adds it manually again the beta will be  deployed as the Fabric secret is stored in the repo. What I did so far is to remove the signing passwords from the gradle file, storing them in Bitrise. In this way only Bitrise can sign the APKs and distribute them through Fabric.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable decision. For smaller infos/passwords you can also use Secret Env Vars, and then just `cat` or similar into the file.